# Creating admin role for the namespace

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, devops, roles, rbac

I created an admin role for the namespace and build that so the role got created. However, I wanted to know whether creating a role to a namespace is enough or we need to create a user and configure some additional changes to apply that role? Please suggest.

Here is the role that I've created:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: admin
  namespace: temp
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch"]
```

Comment: this should be enough, are you facing any issue wit this rule?,also notice that `verbs` is missing `delete` , perhaps use `*` as verb.

Comment: But I checked this role in my local cluster it's not working... So do I need to add any particular users and create any certificate or key for that user??

Comment: you need a human user(like a new team member) or a `service account`  which applications are supped to use?

Comment: i created admin role for the namespace in this case only admin candidates only can have this privileges' but developers don't required. for this case i need clarification

Comment: You need to have certificate and csr created , then approve it then role and role binding. There are many answers on stackoverflow.com  answering the same

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To read more about RBAC Authorization you can visit [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), additionally there are some ready tutorials about configuring the RBAC like those:

1. [Kubernetes Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://www.strongdm.com/blog/kubernetes-rbac-role-based-access-control)
2. [Mixing Kubernetes Roles, RoleBindings, ClusterRoles, and ClusterBindings](https://octopus.com/blog/k8s-rbac-roles-and-bindings)
3. [RBAC, Namespaces and Cluster Roles](https://www.tigera.io/blog/rbac-namespaces-and-cluster-roles/)

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question